# How to send an "end-of-file" marker to a process object's standard input?

Tags: process-control

On a Unix-like system I can do this:

```
$ cat
some text
some text
^D
```

The `cat` utility will echo back everything I send to it until the end-of-file marker <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd> on Windows), when it terminates.

How can I achieve the same thing when running `cat` through [`StartProcess`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/StartProcess.html)?

```
c = StartProcess["cat"]
(* ProcessObject[118] *)

ProcessStatus[c]
(* "Running" *)

WriteString[c, "some text\n"]
(* OutputStream["in:118", 239] *)

ProcessStatus[c]
(* "Running" *)
```

At this point `cat` is still running.  **How can I send it a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> to allow it to terminate?**  Trying to `ReadString[c]` would hang at this point.

Comment: I'd assume `Close@ProcessConnection[c, "StandardInput"]` would accomplish this, but it doesn't seem so...

Comment: I don't know about sending an EOF but you should be able to use `ReadString[c, EndOfBuffer]` to read from a running process without hanging and then use the rather brutal `KillProcess[c]` when done.

Comment: @MikeLimaOscar Sounds like an answer!

Comment: I thought it more a workaround but if you insist 

Comment: Killing is not a clean way to terminate a process, it skips any side effects the process may have after the stream is closed (e.g. waiting for entire input before starting outputting, or it may contact network, do some logging, print a file, or, as Mathematica is often run in a scientific environment, interface with lab hardware).

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe that sending an EOF is necessary in this case.  Use of

```
ReadString[c, EndOfBuffer]
```

should not result in a hang and then simply use

```
KillProcess[c]
```

when done.

Comment: If you try to write some ascii control characters to "c" it still hangs - try `WriteString[c, FromCharacterCode[4]]` (which is what I'd thought would work). +1 anyway!

Comment: @gpap perhaps `BinaryWrite` would be better in that case?

Comment: You are right (as per the  best way to write a char code onto "c") the method still hangs if you do it and then try `ReadString[c, EndOfBuffer]` (in my system at least)

Comment: @gpap Works on my system (unless I have previously aborted a `ReadString[c]`)

Comment: Sorry to waste your time - you are right again - that's exactly what I had done...

Comment: @gpap Correction: Seems to work if it is preceded by "printable" ASCII, otherwise it hangs. The link seems to recover from aborts. (Correcting myself not your comment!)

Comment: Afraid i have to point out, this answer works for "cat", but it wont do for a process that actually waits for stdin to close before generating output.  Try `sort` for example..