# Is there a way to create ZIP OutputStream ?

Tags: export, streams, compression

I want to write data to a file using compression. Is it possible to do that just in time (like in java `ZipOutputStream`). E.g. what I want:

```
zipOutputStream = OpenWrite["file.zip", Compression->"ZIP"];
For[i = 0, i < 1000000, ++i, 
    Write[zipOutputStream, doMyStuff[i]];
]
Close[zipOutputStream];
```

so that the resulting `file.zip` will be a valid zip archive.

Comment: If you were asking about gzip, then the answer would probably be yes.  See `$OutputStreamMethods`.  But I don't know how to get it to work.  BTW you really should consider not using `For` unless you can come up with a very good reason why it's appropriate. Just use `Do`.

Comment: Why should I use `Do` instead of `For`?

Comment: Countless reasons that have been repeated many times here and on other forums: Unreadable, easy to mess up (countless examples of `,`-`;` confusion), the iterator is not localized, it gets unnecessarily verbose (multiple iterators? list iterator?), it doesn't parallelize, etc. And it shows a bad example. A lot of beginner questions would just go away if `For` didn't exist in Mathematica.

Comment: you might work with `StartProcess` and an external compression program.

Comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/134609/12

Comment: @StanislavPoslavsky: I have given an answer which indicates how you can build something on your own. If you want to do that and find a solution, it is welcomed that you answer your own question and accept that answer. If you think that is out of your current ambitions, then you might wait and see if someone else gives a more detailed answer...

Comment: Now having tried this, there are two problems with `StartProcess`:. 1) There is no evident way to direct the process standard out to a file. (this can be worked around)  2) I have been unable to figure out how to signal the end of the data. see  http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/84430/2079

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As mentioned already it's easy to implement this functionality with JLink.
But once you use Java's `ZipOtputStream` you will need to convert your data to list of bytes first. Borrowing java code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14462371/preferred-way-to-use-java-zipoutputstream-and-bufferedoutputstream).

```
<< JLink`
InstallJava[];

openStream[file_] := Module[{fos, bos, zos},
   fos = JavaNew["java.io.FileOutputStream", file~StringJoin~".zip"];
   bos = JavaNew["java.io.BufferedOutputStream", fos];
   zos = JavaNew["java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream", bos];
   zos@putNextEntry[JavaNew["java.util.zip.ZipEntry", file]];
   zos];

closeStream[stream_] := Module[{},
   stream@closeEntry[];
   stream@close[];
   ];

stream = openStream["blah.dat"];

stream@write[{1, 2, 3}]
closeStream[stream];
```

As result you will get **blah.dat.zip** archive that will have **blah.dat** inside.
This is not very useful. We need some sort of serialization. Let's take your example and define

```
doStuff[x_] := x*x
```

We will store squares of 1-1000000 in a zip file:

```
convertToBytes[list_] := 
  Flatten[ToCharacterCode /@ (ToString[#]~StringJoin~"\n" & /@ list)];
stream = openStream["blah.dat"];

stream@write[convertToBytes[doStuff /@ Range[1000000]]]
closeStream[stream];
```

> **Update** @rcollyer proposed to hook into native streams with `DefineOutputStreamMethod` and it actually worked:

```
DefineOutputStreamMethod["Zipped", {
    "ConstructorFunction" -> 
          Function[{name, isAppend, caller, opts}, {True, openStream[name]}],

   "WriteFunction" -> 
          Function[{state, bytes}, state@write[bytes]; {Length[bytes], state}],
   "CloseFunction" -> Function[{state}, closeStream[state]]
}];
```

Now we can work with zipped streams using native methods:

```
starWars = OpenWrite["star-wars.dat", Method -> "Zipped"];

Write[starWars, "yoda forever!"];
Write[starWars, {"Luke", "Leia"}];
Write[starWars, doStuff /@ Range[1000]];

Close[starWars];
```

Comment: I haven't explored this, but there are methods for defining io filters for the streams, i.e. [DefineOutputStreamMethod](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DefineOutputStreamMethod.html). It seems it would be reasonably straightforward to hook your code into the streaming mechanism.

Comment: @rcollyer Thank you! It's really easy to hook into "real" streams.

Comment: Great! (You already had a +1 from me.) And, the input version can then be constructed similarly.

Answer (score 6):

Neither the import format ZIP (nor any of those similar to it like GZIP, TAR or BZIP) nor the function `CreateArchive` do have any documented functionality which would let you do what you want. So I see two possible ways to achieve what you want:

- as george2079 mentioned in his comment, you could use `StartProcess` and an external program. That will of course become somewhat OS dependent.
- you could use JLink to access the java functionality you are referring to directly.

If you get that to work you might have a look at the new stream methods functionality which should in principle let you define a specific output stream method which would behave as you indicated. Unfortunately the documentation of stream methods is not very detailed so I guess it would mean some experimenting to get this running.

Some superfluos spelunking in the `CreateArchive` code indicates that WRI uses `` JLink` `` plus `java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream` there so I think that is the most straightforward path. If you want to have a look at how they do things, you could have a look at the definition of `` CreateArchiveDump`compress `` and `` CreateArchiveDump`addToZIPFile `` which will be available after the first use of `CreateArchive`.