# Why should I avoid the For loop in Mathematica?

Tags: core-language, coding-style, faq

Some people advise against the use of `For` loops in Mathematica. Why?  Should I heed this advice?  What is wrong with `For`?  What should I use instead?

Comment: This comes up so often, I wanted to have something to link to. As always on StackExchange, other answers are welcome.

Comment: As, still, someone not that fluent in Mathematica, and a longtime programmer (mostly C), this was the most useful question/answer I've read - and I have read a bunch of these! Thanks to both the questioner and the responder.

Comment: Related (my own self Q&A): [Alternatives to procedural loops and iterating over lists in Mathematica](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7924/121): *"Explicit loops are often counterproductive in Mathematica, not only taking more keystrokes, but also more execution time. They are also, in my opinion, more prone to mistakes."*

Answer (score 122):

*If you are new to Mathematica, and were directed to this post, first see if you can use [`Table`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html) to solve your problem.*

---

I have often told people, especially beginners, to avoid using `For` in favour of `Do`.  The following is my personal opinion on why using `For` is harmful when learning Mathematica.  If you are a seasoned Mathematica user, you won't find much to learn here. My biggest argument against `For` is that *it hinders learning* by encouraging error-prone, hard to read, and slow code.

[`For`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/For.html) mimics the syntax of the for loop of C-like languages. Many beginners coming from such languages will look for a "for loop" when they start using Mathematica. Unfortunately, `For` gives them lots of ways to shoot themselves in the foot, while providing virtually no benefits over alternatives such as `Do`.  Settling on `For` also tends to delay beginners in discovering more Mathematica-like programming paradigms, such as list-based and functional programming (`Table`, `Map`, etc.)

I want to make it clear at the beginning that the following arguments are not about functional vs procedural programming.  Functional programming is *usually* the better choice in Mathematica, but procedural programming is also clearly needed in many situations. I will simply argue that when we do need a procedural loop, `For` is nearly always the worst choice.  Use `Do` or `While` instead.

#### Use `Do` instead of `For`

The typical use case of `For` is iterating over an integer range.  `Do` will do the same thing better.

- `Do` is more concise, thus both more readable and easier to write without mistakes.  Compare the following:

  ```
  For[i=1, i <= n, i++, 
    f[i]; g[i]; h[i]
  ]
  ```

  ```
  Do[ f[i]; g[i]; h[i], {i, n} ]
  ```

  In `For` we need to use both commas (`,`) and semicolons (`;`) in a way that is almost, but not quite, the opposite of how they are used in C-like languages. This alone is a big source of beginner confusion and mistakes (possibly due to muscle memory).  `,` and `;` are visually similar so it is hard to spot the mistake.
- `For` does not localize the iterator `i`.  A safe `For` needs explicit localization:

  ```
  Module[{i},
    For[i=1, i <= n, i++, ...]
  ]
  ```

  A common mistake is to overwrite the value of a global `i`, possibly defined in an earlier input cell. At other times `i` is used as a symbolic variable elsewhere, and `For` will inconveniently assign a value to it.

  In `Do`,  `i` is a local variable, so we do not need to worry about these things.
- C-like languages typically use 0-based indexing. Mathematica uses 1-based indexing. `for`-loops are typically written to loop through `0..n-1` instead of `1..n`, which is usually the more convenient range in Mathematica.  Notice the differences between

  ```
  For[i=0, i < n, i++, ...]
  ```

  and

  ```
  For[i=1, i <= n, i++, ...]
  ```

  We must pay attention not only to the starting value of `i`, but also `<` vs `<=` in the second argument of `For`. Getting this wrong is a common mistake, and again it is hard to spot visually.
- In C-like languages the for loop is often used to loop through the elements of an array.  The literal translation to Mathematica looks like

  ```
  For[i=1, i <= n, i++,
    doSomething[array[[i]]]
  ]
  ```

  `Do` makes this much simpler and clearer:

  ```
  Do[doSomething[elem], {elem, array}]
  ```
- `Do` makes it easy to use multiple iterators:

  ```
  Do[..., {i, n}, {j, m}]
  ```

  The same requires a nested `For` loop which doubles the readability problems.

#### Transitioning to more Mathematica-like paradigms

A common beginner-written program that we see here on StackExchange collects values in a loop like this:

```
list = {};
For[i=1, i <= n, ++i,
  list = Append[list, i^2]
]
```

This is of course not only complicated, but also slow ($O(n^2)$ complexity instead of $O(n)$).  The better way is to use `Table`:

```
Table[i^2, {i, n}]
```

`Table` and `Do` have analogous syntaxes and their documentation pages reference each other.  Starting out with `Do` makes the transition to `Table` natural. Moving from `Table` to `Map` and other typical functional or vectorized (`Range[n]^2`) constructs is then only a small step.  Settling on `For` as "the standard looping construct" leaves beginners stuck with bad habits.

Another very common question on StackExchange is how to parallelize a `For` loop.  There is no parallel for in Mathematica, but there is a `ParallelDo` and more importantly a `ParallelTable`. The answer is almost always: design the computation so that separate steps of the iteration do not access the same variable.  In other words: just use `Table`.

#### More general versions of `For`

`For` is of course in some ways more flexible than `Do`. It can express a broader range of iteration schemes. If you need something like this, I suggest just using `While` instead.

When we see `for`, we usually expect either a simple iteration through an integer range or through an array. Doing something else, such as modifying the value of the iterator in the loop body is unexpected, therefore confusing.  Using `While` signals that anything can happen in the loop body, so the readers of the code will watch out for such things.

#### When is `For` appropriate?

There are some cases when `For` is useful.  The main example is translating code from other languages. It is convenient to be able to translate analogous for loops, and not have to think about what may be broken by immediately translating to a `Do` or a `Table` (e.g. does the loop modify the iterator in the body?).  Once the translated code works fine, it can be rewritten gradually.

There are existing questions on this, which also discuss other cases:

- [Are there any cases when For[] loops are reasonable?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2158/12)
- [Can this be written well, without loops?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2164/can-this-be-written-well-without-loops)

#### Summary

The problem with `For` is that it hinders learning and makes it very easy for beginners to introduce mistakes into their code.

If you are new to Mathematica, my advice is to forget that `For` exists, at least for a while.  You can *always* accomplish the very same things with `Do` and `While`—use them instead.  Very often you will be able to replace `Do` with a `Table` or even a vectorized expressions. This will help you learn to write effective Mathematica code faster.

If you are unsure about a use of `For`, then ask yourself: do I see a reason why `For` is clearly better here than `Do` or `While`?  If not, don't use it. If yes, you may have found one of the rare good use cases.

Comment: `Range[10]^2` is superior to `Table[i^2, {i, 10}]`

Comment: @Feyre It is, in several ways. And the jump from `Table` to vectorized computation is quite straightforward—another reason to use `Do`, which then leads to `Table`, which then leads to the paradigm you show.  But there is only so much space in one post.  I wrote this up so I can link to it when people ask why they are told to avoid `For`.

Comment: @Feyre I added your example.

Comment: @Szabolcs, what a great answer, lucid and clean+1

Comment: +1 Great post, thanks for taking the time to put it together. I've added a link to this in the "Avoiding procedural loops" answer in the giant pitfalls question.

Comment: +1, but one nit. I've never understood how `Table` is considered more inline with a "functional" paradigm than `For`. There are obvious utilities with using `Table`/`Do` over `For`, but other languages have used similar forms for years, usually expressed as `ForEach` and c++ has gotten in on the act via the [ranged for](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for).

Comment: Avoid `For`, `Do` is better. Avoid `Do`, `Table` is better. Avoid `Table`, `Range^2` is better. When is it good enough?

Comment: @DepressedDaniel when our computations become fast enough to solve the most basic problems in Ramsey Theory ;)  let's start with $R(5,5)$ and work from there...

Comment: @rcollyer `Table` is effectively a _map_ function, rather than a foreach, since it collects results - and of course map is the quintessential example of the functional paradigm.

Comment: @00Dani Yes, `Table` can be implemented in terms of `Map`, but that is likely slower than simply constructing the list on the fly for most cases, e.g. `Table[f[i], {i, 10}]` would be `Map[Block[{i = #}, f[i]]&, Range[10]]` a two step operation. (Yes, there might be optimizations in there.) And, why is collecting the result automatically functional? Functional implies we can pass around functions as top-level objects which `Array` is more akin to. `Table` fits reasonably in functional and procedural programming.

Comment: @rcollyer You are right that `Table` may not be technically a functional construct, but it does have many of the same virtues and it fits better into the language.  *Typically* each element of the table is computed independently, and without side effects.  *Typically*, each evaluation done by `Do` *does* have a side effect (otherwise it would be pointless). This is what makes it possible to auto-compile and even auto-`Parallelize` `Table` relatively easily.

Comment: "_`For` does not localize the iterator i_" -- that alone for me is a sufficient argument to avoid `For`. All the rest are good points, but mostly about style / readability whereas this one actually breaks the functional pattern (I strive to have as few assignments as possible in general) and may lead to hard-to-find bugs (as opposed to simple typo's that Mathematica will tell you about).

Comment: @Szabolcs as a said, it's a nit, and not a large one.

Comment: I agree the principal reason one should default to functional programming in MMA is b/c that leverages the essence of its design. But I wonder if another reason procedural programming is problematic is that MMA doesn't offer some basic procedural functionality one finds in procedural languages. E.g., isn't the given example, `list = {};` `For[i=1, i <= n, ++i, list = Append[list, i^2]]`, O~n^2 because it's *not* an analog to procedural programming? Wouldn't a fairer MMA pseudocode analog to C, but one not avail. in MMA, be `For[i = 1, i <= 10, ++i, list[i] = i^2]`, which would be O~n?

Comment: (continued). Yes, there is `For[i = 1, i <= 10, ++i, list[[i]] = i^2]`, but that will only work if the list has already been initialized, so you can't use that code to initialize it.   Another key issue that it's helpful to make explicit to beginners, to encourage them to avoid a procedural approach (except when necessary), is that MMA's procedural syntax isn't merely different from that of procedural languages (e.g., the commas vs. the semicolons), but in fact much more confusing to code (for nested loops of even moderate complexity) than that of procedural languages.

Comment: @theorist initialization in this case would be akin to allocating an array in another language, e.g. `int list[5];` for c/c++, etc. This can be easily done by setting `list = ConstantArray[0, imax]` for the more complex operations.

Comment: @Szabolcs great post! Would it make sense to mention `Nest`, `Fold` families in your "Transitioning..." section? The process of designing a function for `Nest` immediately addresses a lot of issues and allows arbitrary iteration techniques (even when parallelization is not possible) [This recent question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/134757/list-output-as-a-variable-within-a-forloop-function-changes?noredirect=1&lq=1) demonstrates show messy a simple `For` can be and how easily it can be simplified with `NestList`

Comment: @BlacKow My aim was really just to tell newcomers to avoid `For`, not to promote functional programming, or to show all possible alternatives.  There are other posts for that, [such as the one by Mr. Wizard](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7924/12). I think that `For` alone is causing too much harm, and if I can get people to at least look at the equivalent `Do`, then I am already happy that I started them down on a better path.  The main reason why I wrote this up was so that I won't have to mention the same thing again and again in comments. I can just link here instead.

Comment: I got an automatic flag on this post for excessive comments.  It probably would be good to move the salient points into the answer.

Answer (score 33):

Illustration of the timings required to compute the squares `i^2` from `i=1` to `i=10^n` for `n=1, 2, ..., 7` with the use of `For`, `While`, `Do`, `Table`, and `Range`.

```
for = Table[
  Module[{i},
   For[i = 1, i <= 10^n, i++, i^2] // AbsoluteTiming // First
   ]
  , {n, 1, 7}]

while = Table[
  Module[{i},
   i = 1; While[i <= 10^n, i^2; i++] // AbsoluteTiming // First
   ]
  , {n, 1, 7}]

do = Table[Do[i^2, {i, 10^n}] // AbsoluteTiming // First, {n, 1, 7}]

table = Table[
  Table[i^2, {i, 10^n}]; // AbsoluteTiming // First, {n, 1, 7}]

range = Table[Range[10^n]^2; // AbsoluteTiming // First, {n, 1, 7}]
```

(By the way, look how concise are the codes of `Do`, `Table` and `Range` compared to `For` and `While`.)

The timings for `10^7` squares (i.e., `n=7`):

```
Last /@ {for, while, do, table, range}
```

> {7.32907, 8.23668, 2.44558, 0.132735, 0.036395}

And a plot (vertical axis in log-scale):

```
ListLogPlot[{for, while, do, table, range}, Frame -> True, 
 PlotRange -> All, Joined -> True, ImageSize -> 400, 
 FrameLabel -> {"n", "Log[AbsoluteTiming] (sec)"}, 
 PlotLabels -> {"For", "While", "Do", "Table", "Range"}]
```

[image]

`Do` is about $3\times$ faster than `For/While`; for this particular application, one could (and should) employ `Table/Range`, which are two orders of magnitude faster than `For`.

Comment: Not sure that's a fair comparison, because: (1) `Do`, for example, throws away everything calculated (returning `Null`) whereas `Table`, for example, actually returns the list of squares; and (2) calculating `i^2` is relatively trivial and misleadingly magnifies the effect of the looping construct used.

Comment: @murray I've made it a community wiki; feel free to improve.

Comment: @murray In general, you are right: one of the things the benchmark shows is the performance of the looping construct itself, as `i^2` is so fast. In more typical uses it is the speed of looping that is negligible compared to the loop body. But there's more here: `Table` is fast because of auto-compilation.  Auto-compilation is possible because of the functional nature of `Table`: each element of the table is computed independently of the others and *usually* without side effects.

Comment: @murray In contrast, each evaluation done by `Do` will have side effects, otherwise it would be pointless.  Usually, that side effect is changing the same global variable (e.g. accumulating a sum), which makes the evaluations non-independent.  Thus `Do` does not auto-compile.  Similarly, `Table` is immediately parallelizable while `Do` isn't.  My original answer wasn't simply about performance. There's much more to it: readability, manageability, etc. But I think it is true that using `For` can *significantly* hinder performance. Of course this applies to Mathematica only, not other languages.

Comment: +1 for actual science, even if a microbenchmark-y one

Comment: For most beginners, the reason to avoid For is simpler: For requires you to set up the behavior of index variables in detail, specifying the start point, increment size and continuation test. Do and Table in their most paradigmatic forms favor a simple loop whose value begins at 1 and ends with an explicit final value.

Answer (score 12):

The functional paradigm, exemplified by this code:

```
Map[(#^2) &, Range[10^7]] // AbsoluteTiming
```

will usually result in the fastest execution because it takes advantage of the architecture of the machine.  Both the CPU and the memory are optimized for sequential access, so when you pass a function over a list of data to transform that data, the code stays in one place, taking advantage of locality (no code-cache misses), and the data is accessed as one continuous stream of bytes.  The above line of code takes 0.281 seconds to complete on my computer, while the line below ran for well over an hour and only produced a list 1,190,218 elements long:

```
out = {};
For[i = 1, i <= 10^7, ++i, AppendTo[out, i^2]] // AbsoluteTiming
```

Comment: The fastest way is in fact using array arithmetic (i.e. "vectorization"): `Range[10^7]^2`.  `Map` needs to evaluate Mathematica code for each element, which is slower than handling the entire array with a low-level implementation.  To be precise, `Map` will auto-compile `#^2&`, which gives a considerable speedup. But it is still not competitive with parallelized array arithmetic that makes use of SIMD instructions.

Comment: But generally you are correct.  If this were not something that can be expressed with basic vector arithmetic, then `Map` would be a good way.  It is only purely numerical operations on packed arrays that will benefit for vectorization.

Answer (score 6):

A problem that arose in a recent Q&A, which is solved by `Outer` (not yet mentioned here), was

- *How to iterate a function over the cartesian product of lists and store the values generated?*

For the sake of illustration, take two lists:

```
a = {"a", "b", "c"};
b = {1, 2, 3, 4};
```

We want to apply a function `f` to each ordered pair of elements from `a` and `b`.  A for-loop way would be as follows:

```
m = Length[a];
n = Length[b];
table = ConstantArray[0, {m, n}];
For[i = 1, i <= m, i++,
  For[j = 1, j <= n, j++,
   table[[i, j]] = f[a[[i]], b[[j]]]
   ]
  ];
table
```

> ```
> (* see output below *)
> ```

The following does the same:

```
table = Outer[f, a, b]
```

> ```
> (*
>   {{f["a", 1], f["a", 2], f["a", 3], f["a", 4]},
>    {f["b", 1], f["b", 2], f["b", 3], f["b", 4]},
>    {f["c", 1], f["c", 2], f["c", 3], f["c", 4]}}
> *)
> ```

For a product three lists, use

```
Outer[f, a, b, c]
```

And so on.

The same can be done with `Table`:

```
table = Table[f[ai, bj, {ai, a}, {bj, b}] (* less efficient than Outer *)
table = Table[f[a[[i]], b[[j]], {i, m}, {j, n}] (* much less efficient *)
```

Like `Outer`, `Table` can be extended to higher dimensional products.